# Are there practical or technical advantages to using 2-space vs 4-space indents?

Tags: coding-style, compatibility

Aside from taste, habit and personal preference, are there any advantages to using 2-space vs. 4-space indents while coding?

For instance, in this [Google style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Indentation), it is recommended to use 2-space indents for CSS.

Are there any technical advantages to using one over the other, for instance when transferring data between different systems?

Are there widely accepted conventions? (that possibly differ from language to language)

Comment: If you use a tab of 8 chars, on a 4 tabs indentation you get 32 spaces. You get 16 spaces with a tab of 4 chars. You get 8 spaces on a tab of 2 chars. Today, 2 or 4 characters tabs are about preference of readability. Even on a very good segmented code you can have 3 or 4 nested indentations. I prefer 2 chars to avoid code getting stacked against the right side of the screen (on code wrap). All depending on monitor size.

Comment: Since when is highlighting advantages opinion based?

Comment: @RoboRobok Whether or not something is an advantage is subjective. Anyway, OP has asked 3 questions here, all pretty broad. Quite off-topic.

Comment: @ggorlen no, not always. There are many things that are OBJECTIVELY better than others and everyone seems to realize that except Stack Overflow community 

Comment: @RoboRobok Python is objectively better with 4 spaces over 2 because it doesn't have braces or `end` blocks, but I think it's pretty much up for grabs in any other language. Anyway, as much as every question closed as opinion has some derisive comment about SO's closure policies and community, I'm pretty sure this site would be much less useful as a Reddit or Quora where people just state opinions back and forth. People like to bag on SO as being "hostile" but consider that the topical restrictions are part of what makes the site good.

Comment: @ggorlen I've seen dozens of great questions here that have been closed just because of the wording. Looks like a lot of users here lack the soft skills to distinguish opinions from good practice advice.

Comment: "Good practice advice" sounds likes like "opinion-based". That's not a practical, answerable programming problem. The site isn't about offering advice, it's about answering technical questions, like "why does my program crash when I concatenate a string and an integer?". Quora or Reddit are sites for discussions about which indentation is better practice.

Comment: @ggorlen "Aside from taste, habit and personal preference". Basically, besides opinion, is what I actually meant with my question. I don't really see a way to phrase it better, but I think most importantly: I don't see how my question (or two, if you like), would be opinion-based.

Comment: @ggorlen Not to nitpick, but whether or not something *is* an advantage, is not opinion-based.

Comment: @Pim I don't think there's much left to this after you take out those things. All of the answers here are just opinions, or at least heavily context-dependent. Er... yes, whether something is an advantage can very much be opinion-based. One person's advantage is another person's disadvantage. Even if this question wasn't opinion-based, it's still extremely broad and not really a practical, answerable programming problem as outlined in the [help]. The closure is correct. If you disagree, I suggest bringing the question to meta.

Comment: For example, see [Asking questions about advantages & disadvantages on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258308/asking-questions-about-advantages-disadvantages-on-so)

Comment: @ggorlen Whether something is an advantage or not, is a factual question. Whether you consider it an advantage is something else. And yes, I disagree with the closure, because it was very much a technical question at its core. Besides, it was open for a long time, and as you can see, there are people with 500k+ reputation here that have provided answers. But yeah, someone comes in one day and considers the question opinion-based (very much an opinion by itself), and it gets closed... Not gonna do the effort to take this to meta, but I do think mods sometimes judge too quickly.

Comment: @Pim Consider: is it advantageous to be C.E.O. of Twitter? That's clearly opinion-based. Some people see it as an advantage (you have a huge amount of power), and others see it as a disadvantage (you blew $44 billion and are about to wreck the platform and whatever you had left of your reputation). 2 vs 4 spaces, same. This post was closed by 5 people, not "someone". None of these individuals were moderators. That's community consensus. If the closure was in error, there's a reopen process, and this post hasn't passed it. There's no point in discussing this here further, it belongs on meta.

Comment: BTW, rep doesn't matter much. Many of those people picked low-hanging fruit back when the site was in its infancy and the rules hadn't solidified yet, or continue to answer off-topic, low-quality questions to get rep. They're often the "anything goes, just upvote and accept my answer"-type folks who'd rather answer a poorly-asked or off-topic question than mark it as a clear duplicate or close it. Making the site useful for the community amounts to good curation, not attempting to get rep at all costs.

Comment: @ggorlen So then it's not. For the reasons you state. If you could find a more objective measure (like compatibility for different charsets/systems, or filesize, for instance), then the question actually could have a different answer than "no".

Comment: It's pretty clear that 2-spaces gives a smaller file size than 4. I grant that that's objective, but also trivial.

Comment: @ggorlen Not necessarily! But my point was, I'm not asking what the best programming language is here. Nor am I asking if it's an advantage to be the CEO of Twitter (which imo, is actually an interesting question).

Comment: No, you're not, but these are metaphors used to illustrate aspects of what you _are_ asking, specifically, "list the advantages" is both opinion-based and too broad. And if it's only too broad instead of both, it's still off topic. Again, instead of continuing to debate here, I suggest posting about it on meta and see what the community thinks. I won't be able to convince you here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are no clear "technical" advantages one way or the other.  Indeed the only "technical" issue I can think of is the impact on the number of bytes in a source file.

- If you represent the indents using space characters (ASCII SP), then 2 spaces is 2 characters fewer than 4 spaces.
- If you allow TAB characters to be used, then (on Windows) a TAB indents by up to 4 spaces, so TAB characters result in fewer characters.  But the flip side is that a TAB conventionally indents by up to 8 spaces on many other operating systems, so if you want your source code to look nice on all platforms you shouldn't use TAB for indentation.

And besides, it is common practice to "minify" CSS, Javascript and web-associated languages to make websites "faster".  Among other things, that will strip out the indentation, rendering this minor technical difference to be moot.

(For the human readable version of a CSS, the saving in transmission time / storage space is too trivial to worry about.  Today's systems are optimized for the mass market, where storing and moving around gigabyte-sized files (movies) is common-place.  Source code pales into insignificance.)

---

As to "practical" advantages, I guess it may be easier to view and edit files if you don't waste too much screen real-estate with deep indentation.  From that perspective 2 character indentation is better than 4 or 8 character indentation.  However this borders on being a "personal taste" issue ... unless:

- you have to use a device that can only display (say) 80 columns, or
- you have to work with code-style rules that restrict you to 80 columns.

---

> Are there widely accepted conventions?

In general no.

In some languages, maybe, but I can't think of any.  Even in Java, the most common convention for indentation is 4 spaces, but others are acceptable.

Answer (score 32):

From: [**Linux Kernel Coding Style**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html)

> Tabs are 8 characters, and thus indentations are also 8 characters. There are heretic 
>   movements that try to make indentations 4 (or even 2!) characters deep, and that is akin 
>   to trying to define the value of PI to be 3.
>
> Rationale: The whole idea behind indentation is to clearly define where a block of 
>   control starts and ends. Especially when you've been looking at your screen for 20 
>   straight hours, you'll find it a lot easier to see how the indentation works if you have 
>   large indentations.
>
> Now, some people will claim that having 8-character indentations makes the code move 
>   too far to the right, and makes it hard to read on a 80-character terminal screen. The 
>   answer to that is that if you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed 
>   anyway, and should fix your program.
>   In short, 8-char indents make things easier to read, and have the added benefit of 
>   warning you when you're nesting your functions too deep. Heed that warning

Comment: Linus [does say](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blame/master/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst), though: "Coding style is very personal, and I won't force my views on anybody, but this is what goes for anything that I have to be able to maintain, and I'd prefer it for most other things too"

Comment: nice, really sounds like Linus' tone so I'll take it

Answer (score 19):

I used two spaces in my books because otherwise you run out of horizontal space pretty quickly. I use four in the IDE.

It used to be a physical tab, eight spaces, in the old days of course, but code got too nested for that many decades ago.